# How to achieve a 4 directional, mobile-friendly, scroll view with CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-grid

[image: basic idea of hero-area]

Imagine a hero-area (div1) in CSS Grid, with a 100vh, taking up the entire screen.
4 buttons, each smooth scrolling the user towards a div, changing direction depending on which button was clicked.

▲ up: div2

▼ down: div3

◄ left: div4

► right: div5

[image: Grid CSS layout]

Once the user has clicked a button... it would take the user another click on a HOME/#index.html
and the view would smooth scroll inwards, direction depending on whichever div it came from. div2 would scroll down, div4 would scroll right.

Once you're inside a div, it should feel like being on a regular page, with no view or ability to scroll to the other divs, but with ability to scroll inside the div itself.

Perhaps I am overthinking things... maybe this is best achieved using some javascript slider script?

What would be the most elegant CSS Grid solution? Directional smooth scroll? Bonus points for utilizing VueJs!

*ferociously sips his coffee*

```css
:root {
  --radius: 5px;
  --padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas:
    "    .        content1       .     "
    " content4    hero-area   content2 "
    "    .        content3       .     "
  ;
}

#hero-area {
  background: #c9268d;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding-top: var(--padding);
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, 80px) 60px;
  grid-gap: .2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content:center;
}

#content1 {
  background: #d81b60;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding-top: var(--padding);
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

#content2 {
  background: #b31077;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding-top: var(--padding);
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

#content3 {
  background: #c51162;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding-top: var(--padding);
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}
#content4 {
  background: #bf1179;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  padding-top: var(--padding);
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div id="hero-area">Hero-area</div>
  <div id="content1">Content 1</div>
  <div id="content2">Content 2</div>
  <div id="content3">Content 3</div>
  <div id="content4">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it might be easier to have the content divs (1,2,3,4) smooth scroll in front of the hero-area as it does the opposite, creating the illusion of the viewport moving? I am still looking for ideas on how to carry out this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have a full answer but I would like to provide you with some inspiration using css `scroll-snap` and then I'd recommend using JS to tell the buttons to scroll to each corresponding div.

```css
    html {
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    }

    .container > div {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;

      scroll-snap-align: start;
    }

    #hero-area {
      grid-row: 2 / 3;
      grid-column: 2 / 3;

      background-color: gray;
    }

    #content1 {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;

      background-color: #123456;
    }

    #content2 {
      grid-column: 3 / 4;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;

      background-color: #234567;
    }

    #content3 {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      grid-row: 3 / 4;

      background-color: #345678;
    }

    #content4 {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;

      background-color: #456789;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="hero-area">Hero-area</div>
  <div id="content1">Content 1</div>
  <div id="content2">Content 2</div>
  <div id="content3">Content 3</div>
  <div id="content4">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I have only tested it in Firefox.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_scroll-snap-stop.

Comment: Looks very very promising. How would I go about and block the scrolling via mouse blocking? The white (non-div) corners should not be accessible.

I might have been overthinking this entirely... do you think it possible to somehow only load the hero-area to begin with and then gradually load the rest of the divs depending on which button is clicked?

Thanks for this.

Comment: I think everything else has to be done with JS. You best be very critical with what I'm about to say because I am an absolute novice at best in JS but I would add an even listener on scroll and just check the scroll position to determine if i'm in an unallowed zone.

What do you mean with gradually loading? Would it be okay to just hide the other areas and only start with the main one and expand (show) other divs on click?

Comment: Hi, was in no man's land without any wifi :) I would be okay with people not having access to these corners. I'm considering how this kind of layout might be achieved... could be you just create the illusion of movement, by having the other pages slide in  and out directionally.